# Get upload progress with Meteor

Tags: meteor

I was about to use XHR to send a file to the server when I realized that I don't have an end-point due to lack of routing.

Then I read [this article](https://gist.github.com/dariocravero/3922137) and discovered I could potentially do file uploads by taking advantage of `Meteor.methods`. Now my upload looks something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $(document.body).html(Meteor.render(Template.files));
    $(document).on('drop', function(dropEvent) {
        _.each(dropEvent.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files, function(file) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(fileLoadEvent) {
                Meteor.call('uploadFile', file, reader.result);
            };
            reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
        });
        dropEvent.preventDefault();
    });

    $(document).bind('dragover dragenter', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });

});
```

And in `server/main.js` I have this:

```
var require = __meteor_bootstrap__.require; // should I even be doing this? looks like an internal method
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

Meteor.methods({
    uploadFile: function(fileInfo, fileData) {
        var fn = path.join('.uploads',fileInfo.name);
        fs.writeFile(fn, fileData, 'binary', function(err) {
            if(err) {
                throw new Meteor.Error(500, 'Failed to save file.', err);
            } else {
                console.log('File saved to '+fn);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Which just writes it to disk. This seems to work, but I don't know what technology Meteor is using to pass the data to that method on the server, and I don't know how to get progress info back.

Normally I'd attach an event listener to the `xhr` object,

```
xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", uploadProgress, false);
```

but I don't think I have access to one with `.methods`. Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 6):

I've been working on this as well, and I have some code that works.

To clarify first:

> This seems to work, but I don't know what technology Meteor is using to pass the data to that method on the server, and I don't know how to get progress info back.

Meteor has a [WebSockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) connection with the server and it uses this as a transport. So every time you call [Meteor.call](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_call) or [Meteor.apply](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_apply) it will [EJSON](http://docs.meteor.com/#ejson) encode your parameters (if any), call the function server-side, and return you the response transparently.

The trick here is to then use [HTML5's FileReader Api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications) to read the file in chunks (important because large files will crash your browser otherwise) and perform a Meteor.call() for every chunk.

Your code is doing two things that didn't work well for me:

1. It's reading the file as a Binary String: I found that using Base64 is a lot more reliable. You say your code uploads, but have you checked file checksums to make sure they're the same file?
2. It's reading the file all at once. Large files (100s of MB) will cause performance issues, and in my experience even crash your browser.

Ok, to your question now. How to tell how much of the file you've uploaded? You can make your chunks small enough so that you can use chunks_sent / total_chunks as a metric for that. **Alternatively** you could call Session.set( 'progress', current_size / total_size ) from the Meteor server-side call and bind it to an element so that it updates.

This is a jQuery plugin that I've been working on to wrap this functionality. It's not complete, but it uploads files and it may be helpful to you. It currently only gets files via drag drop.. there's no "browse" button.

**Disclaimer:** I am quite new to Meteor & node, so some things may not be done the "recommended" way, but I'll improve it over time and eventually give it a home in Github.

```
;(function($) {

    $.uploadWidget = function(el, options) {

        var defaults = {
            propertyName: 'value',
            maximumFileSize: 1073741824, //1GB

            messageTarget: null
        };

        var plugin = this;

        plugin.settings = {}


        var init = function() {
            plugin.settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
            plugin.el = el;

            if( !$(el).attr('id') || !$(el).attr('id').length ){
                $(el).attr('id', 'uploadWidget_' + Math.round(Math.random()*1000000));
            }

            if( plugin.settings.messageTarget == null ){
                plugin.settings.messageTarget = plugin.el;
            }

            initializeDropArea();
        };


        // Returns a human-friendly string representation of bytes
        var getBytesAsPrettyString = function( bytes ){

            var sizes = ['Bytes', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB'];
            if (bytes == 0) return 'n/a';
            var i = parseInt(Math.floor(Math.log(bytes) / Math.log(1024)));
            return Math.round(bytes / Math.pow(1024, i), 2) + ' ' + sizes[i];

        };


        // Throws an exception if the file (from a drop event) is unacceptable
        var assertFileIsAcceptable = function( file ){

            if( file.size > plugin.settings.maximumFileSize ){
                throw 'Files can\'t be larger than ' + getBytesAsPrettyString(plugin.settings.maximumFileSize);
            }

            //if( !file.name.match(/^.+?\.pdf$/i) ){
            //    throw 'Only pdf files can be uploaded.';
            // }

        };


        var setMainMessage = function( message ){

            $(plugin.settings.messageTarget).text( message );

        };


        plugin.getUploader = function(){

            return plugin.uploader;

        };


        var initializeDropArea = function(){

            var $el = $(plugin.el);

            $.event.props.push("dataTransfer");

            $el.bind( 'dragenter dragover dragexit', function(){
                event.stopPropagation();
                event.preventDefault();
            });

            $el.bind( 'drop', function( event ){

                var slices;
                var total_slices;

                var processChunkUpload = function( blob, index, start, end ){

                    var chunk;

                    if (blob.webkitSlice) {
                        chunk = blob.webkitSlice(start, end);
                    } else if (blob.mozSlice) {
                        chunk = blob.mozSlice(start, end);
                    } else {
                        chunk = blob.slice(start,end);
                    }

                    var reader = new FileReader();

                    reader.onload = function(event){

                        var base64_chunk = event.target.result.split(',')[1];

                        slices--;

                        $el.text( slices + ' out of ' + total_slices + ' left' );

                        Meteor.apply(
                            'saveUploadFileChunk',
                            [file_name, base64_chunk, slices+1],
                            { wait: true }
                        );
                    };

                    reader.readAsDataURL(chunk);
                };


                event.stopPropagation();
                event.preventDefault();
                event.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy';

                if( !event.dataTransfer.files.length ){
                    return;
                }

                const BYTES_PER_CHUNK = 1024 * 1024; // 1MB chunk sizes.


                var blob = event.dataTransfer.files[0];
                var file_name = blob.name;

                var start = 0;
                var end;
                var index = 0;

                // calculate the number of slices we will need
                slices = Math.ceil(blob.size / BYTES_PER_CHUNK);
                total_slices = slices;

                while(start < blob.size) {
                    end = start + BYTES_PER_CHUNK;
                    if(end > blob.size) {
                        end = blob.size;
                    }

                    processChunkUpload( blob, index, start, end );

                    start = end;
                    index++;
                }


            });

        };

        init();

    }

})(jQuery);
```

And this is my meteor published method.

```
Meteor.methods({

        // this is TOTALLY insecure. For demo purposes only.
        // please note that it will append to an existing file if you upload a file by the same name..
        saveUploadFileChunk: function ( file_name, chunk, chunk_num ) {

                var require = __meteor_bootstrap__.require;
                var fs = require('fs');
                var crypto = require('crypto')

                var shasum = crypto.createHash('sha256');
                shasum.update( file_name );

                var write_file_name = shasum.digest('hex');

                var target_file = '../tmp/' + write_file_name;

                fs.appendFile(
                        target_file,
                        new Buffer(chunk, 'base64'),
                        {
                                encoding: 'base64',
                                mode: 438,
                                flag: 'a'
                        }
                        ,function( err ){

                                if( err ){

                                        console.log('error ' + err);
                                }

                                console.log( 'wrote ' + chunk_num );

                        }
                );

                return write_file_name;

        }
});
```

HTH

Comment: "have you check file checksums to make sure they're the same file" -- No, I didn't, but they were images. I opened them after they were uploaded and they weren't corrupt. Base64 encoding them will make them about 4 times larger, won't it? `Session.set` syncs back to the client-side via WebSockets as well doesn't it? Aren't you adding overhead of sending data *both* ways just to get the upload progress? How does XHR work? I assume the progress should be computable from client-side only, no?

Comment: I did find a way to do this BTW, but it bypasses Meteor altogether; Meteor builds on [connect](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/), which you can access directly so that you can create an endpoint for your XHR call. It's a bit sketchy though (in particular, it doesn't like you accessing certain variables in your server-side callback; they have to be in Fibers), so I'm still looking for better solutions.

Comment: BinaryString should work because of EJSON, but I just had trouble with it. It was probably unrelated. About Session.set overhead, yes but it's negligible. As far as I understand the WebSocket connection is persistent so you save on negotiation plus the amount of data being returned (for progress) is too small to matter..

TBH accessing connect directly seems a bit hackish, but I suppose it would have to be done in order to support non-html5 uploads (regular POST) etc.

Comment: I'm hoping the Meteor devs provide us with a better API for streaming data; then we wouldn't have to do these hacks. Still not sure which approach is best at this point.

Comment: @thatjuan Thank you very much for that great tutorial! Never having worked with the FileReader API before, I took the liberty to create my chunked FileReader upload based on your suggestion. I am at a point where everything works almost properly, but I am having an issue with reassembling the chunks. Thus my files end up corrupted on the server side. If you are interested feel free to have a look at my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19097592/readasdataurl-corrupted-output maybe you can spot what I am doing wrong.

Comment: @mritz_p Glad this helped.. This works well for small files, but I actually ran into the same issue you did with corruption of larger files. The reason that happens is because you can't guarantee the order in which the chunks are arriving. A simple solution was to keep a tally of the chunk indexes on the client side, pass them on to the server side and use them to re-stitch your file. You can write temp files named temp_upload_0, temp_upload_1, etc.. and then join them when you've received all of the chunks.. HTH

Comment: @thatjuan Thank you very much for your reply. I have reworked the process, so that temporary files are written to the server first to then be merged on the server. Intereistingly enough I still end up with corrupted files through minor differences on the area where the files are merged.

Comment: @mritz_p Two things to watch for. On the server side, obviously make sure the chunks are reassembled in the correct order. JS Objects don't guarantee order, so I used numeric indexes and then just loop from x=0 to x=number_of_chunks to make sure they go in the right order. Second, watch out to make sure you have the correct encoding on both sides. I'll try to make some time to post an updated example.

Comment: Hey @thatjuan! Thanks for your help and patience. I took care for the factors you have mentioned, however I was still "missing" a byte at the places where the file was merged. The following change solved my problem. Replace ```end = start + (chunkSize - 1) >= file.size ? file.size : start + (chunkSize - 1);``` with ```end = (start + chunkSize) >= file.size ? file.size : (start + chunkSize);```