# readAsDataURL corrupted output

Tags: meteor, filereader

I have coded a meteor App, sending slices of *binary* data to a server with the help of the FileReader API.

The method processing the slices on the client side:

```
var readSlice = function() {
    var start, end;

    start = chunk * chunkSize;

    if (start > file.size) {
        start = end + 1;
    }

    end = start + (chunkSize - 1) >= file.size ? file.size : start + (chunkSize - 1);

    fileReader.onload = function(event) {
        if (++chunk <= chunks) {
            Meteor
                .apply("saveChunk", [ event.target.result.split(',')[1], file.name, clientRegistration, now, (chunk === chunks) ], {
                    wait : true
                });

            readSlice();
        } else {
            /*
             * TODO Notify the GUI
             */
            console.log("reading done");
        }
    };

    fileReader.readAsDataURL(blobSlice.call(file, start, end));
};
```

The slices are received by the server in a properly order and are merged in the following fashion:

```
saveChunk : function(chunk, name, registration, timestamp, last) {

    ...

    tempFile = Meteor.fileTemp + "/" + identifier;

    fs.appendFile(tempFile, new Buffer(chunk, "base64"), {
    encoding : "base64",
    mode : 438,
    flag : "w"
    }, function(error) {
        if (error) {
            throw (new Meteor.Error(500, "Failed to save file.", err));
        }
    });
}
```

This process works almost fine. However the are minor differences in the file, leading to a corrupted output. The binary differences occur at the point in the file where the output ist splitted, so maybe there is something wrong with the split call on the `event.target.result` property, or maybe I am missing something obvious in term of encoding...?

The problem seems to be related to the splitting since a diff of the merged file with the original file shows the following interesting pattern:

[image: The pattern of the merged file]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The corrupted data was result of a simple calculation mistake:

Using

```
end = (start + chunkSize ) >= file.size ? file.size : (start + chunkSize);
```

instead of

```
end = start + (chunkSize - 1) >= file.size ? file.size : start + (chunkSize - 1);
```

fixed the Problem.